# React hook use class object as useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A bit new to React here.

While developing a personal project based on React, I often came up against scenarios where I needed child components to update state passed down to it by a parent, and have the updated state available in both child and parent components.

I know React preaches a top-down flow of immutable data only, but is there an elegant way of solving this issue?

The way I came up with is as shown below. It gets the job done, but it looks and feels ugly, bloated, and it makes me think I'm missing something obvious here that a well-established framework like React would've definitely accounted for in a more intuitive way.

As a simple example, assume that I have a couple of nested components:

```
Root
  Author
    Post
      Comment
```

And that I need each child component to be able to modify the state such that it is also accessible to its parent component as well. A use case might be that you could interact with the `Comment` component to edit a comment, and then interact with a `SAVE` button defined in the `Root` component to save the entire state to a database or something like that.

The way I presently handle such scenarios is this:

```
const Root = ({}) => {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        author: {
            name: 'AUTHOR',
            post: {
                content: 'POST',
                comment: {
                    message: 'COMMENT'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    const onEditAuthor = value => {
        setData({ author: value });
    }

    const onSave = () => {
      axios.post('URL', data);
    }

    return <>
      <Author author={data.author} onEditAuthor={onEditAuthor} />
      <button onClick={() => onSave()}>SAVE</button>
    </>

}


const Author = ({ author, onEditAuthor }) => {

    const onEditPost = value => {
        onEditAuthor({ name: author.name, post: value });
    }

    return <Post post={author.post} onEditPost={onEditPost} />

}


const Post = ({ post, onEditPost }) => {

    const onEditComment = value => {
        onEditPost({ content: post.content, comment: value });
    }

    return <Comment comment={post.comment} onEditComment={onEditComment} />

}



const Comment = ({ comment, onEditComment }) => {

    return <input defaultValue={comment.message} onChange={ev => onEditComment({ message: ev.target.value })} />

}
```

When you change the `Comment`, it calls the `Post.onEditComment()` handler, which in turn calls the `Author.onEditPost()` handler, which finally calls the `Root.onEditAuthor()` handler. This finally updates the state, causing a re-render and propagates the updated state all the way back down.

It gets the job done. But it is ugly, bloated, and looks very wrong in the sense that the `Post` component has an unrelated `onEditComment()` method, the `Author` component has an unrelated `onEditPost()` method, and the `Root` component has an unrelated `onEditAuthor()` method.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Additionally, when the state finally changes, all components that rely on this state are re-rendered whether they directly use the `comment` property or not, as the entire object reference has changed.

I came across `https://hookstate.js.org/` library which looks awesome. However, I found that this doesn't work when the state is an instance of a class with methods. The proxied object has methods but without `this` reference bound properly. I would love to hear someone's solution to this as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example illustrates the case of ["prop drilling"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling).

> Prop drilling (also called "threading") refers to the process you have to go through to get data to parts of the React Component tree.
> Prop drilling can be a good thing, and it can be a bad thing. Following some good practices [as mentioned above](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling), you can use it as a feature to make your application more maintainable.

The issue with "prop drilling", is that it is not really that scalable when you have an app with many tiers of nested components that needs alot of shared state.

An alternative to this, is some sort of ["global state management"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) - and there are tons of libraries out there that handles this for you. Picking the right one, is a task for you

I'd recommend reading these two articles to get a little more familiar with the concepts:

- [Prop Drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)
- [Application State Management with React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the general idea of passing down both a value and a setter:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState('default stuff')

  return (
    <Child stuff={stuff} setStuff={setStuff} />
  )
}

const Child = ({ stuff, setStuff }) => (
  <input value={stuff} onChange={(e) => setStuff(e.target.value)} />
)
```

But more in general, I think your main problem is attempting to use the shape of the POST request as your state structure. `useState` is intended to be used for individual values, not a large structured object. Thus, at the root level, you would have something more like:

```
const [author, setAuthor] = useState('AUTHOR')
const [post, setPost] = useState('POST')
const [comment, setComment] = useState('CONTENT')

const onSave = () => {
  axios.post('URL', {
    author: {
      name: author,
      post: {
        content: post,
        comment: {
          message: comment,
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```

And then pass them down individually.

Finally, if you have a lot of layers in between and don't want to have to pass a bunch of things through all of them (also known as "prop drilling"), you can pull all of those out into a context such as:

```
const PostContext = createContext()

const Root = () => {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('AUTHOR')
  const [post, setPost] = useState('POST')
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('CONTENT')

  const onSave = useCallback(() => {
    axios.post('URL', {
      author: {
        name: author,
        post: {
          content: post,
          comment: {
            message: comment,
          },
        },
      },
    })
  }, [author, comment, post])

  return (
    <PostContext.Provider
      value={{
        author,
        setAuthor,
        post,
        setPost,
        comment,
        setComment,
      }}
    >
      <Post />
    </PostContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext for more info

Comment: The code provided was meant more as an example. The `ContextProvider` approach seems interesting and I shall look into it in a bit more detail next. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use redux instead of doing so much props work, once you create your states with redux they will be global and accesible from other components. https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how using redux would change this code, if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: Redux is kind of big library to explain in a post that's why I shared the documentation link however there is easier option if you want to have a look but not popular as redux in react world. Context Api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html